# Collapse on the sum of one variable but the mean of the other

Tags: stata

I have the following dataset that I wish to collapse to create a firm1 - firm2 - year level dataset:

```
clear

input str32 Firm_1 str32 Firm_2    year number_employees str32 blah1  str32 blah2  returns 
           "Rathon"    "Hass"      2010      4000               hey    hello        40
           "Rathon"    "Hass"      2010      6000               hey    hello        20
           "Rathon"    "Hass"      2012     12000               money    fame       10
           "Rathon"    "Broq"      2012     12000               dime     bunk       50
           "Birlar"    "Goth"      2008      1000               shop     ladder     30
           "Birlar"    "Goth"      2008      7000               shop     ladder     70
end
```

I want the final dataset to be shrunk so that each observation represents the same `firm_1` and `firm_2` for the same `year`. Hence, it will look like the following:

```
           Firm_1       Firm_2    year number_employees  blah1    blah2    returns
           "Rathon"    "Hass"      2010     10000          hey     hello     30 
           "Rathon"    "Hass"      2012     12000         money    fame      10
           "Rathon"    "Broq"      2012     12000         dime     bunk      50
           "Birlar"    "Goth"      2008      8000         shop     ladder    50
```

However, when I use `collapse` in the following manner:

```
collapse (sum) number_employees, by ( Firm_1 Firm_2 year)
```

the command drops the variables `blah_1` and `blah_2`. Is there a way to retain them? Additionally, `returns` should be averaged while collapsing the observations, and not added up like we do for the `number_employees`

Comment: The way this is usually done is by collapsing and then merging the results in the original dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with your example:

```
collapse (sum) number_employees (mean) returns , by(Firm_1 Firm_2 blah* year) 

list 

     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
     | Firm_1   Firm_2   year   blah1    blah2   number~s   returns |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | Birlar     Goth   2008    shop   ladder       8000        50 |
  2. | Rathon     Broq   2012    dime     bunk      12000        50 |
  3. | Rathon     Hass   2010     hey    hello      10000        30 |
  4. | Rathon     Hass   2012   money     fame      12000        10 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As long as there is one-to-one correspondence as you desire, variables constant within each group can be added to the `by()` option. More obviously, the documented syntax allows different statistics to be calculated for the same or different variables.